# flutter loading page not working / routes function not working

Tags: flutter

I have implemented a routes function to try and get my loading page to appear first, please see the code below. However, it is skipping the loading page and going straight to the home page, can anyone help? (code below) - Many thanks in advance!!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './home.dart';
import './profile.dart';
import 'loading.dart';
import 'search.dart';

void route() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  routes: {
    '/loading': (context) => LoadingPage(),
    '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
    '/profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
  },
));


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    HomePage(),
    SearchPage(),
    ProfilePage(),
  ];
```

Comment: Can you please paste the full code as I am not able to see where are you calling the MyApp class?

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this line bellow to your MaterialApp?

...

***initialRoute: '/loading'***

...